# AngularJS : get object by id from factory

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-service, angular-promise, angularjs-factory

I have a `factory` to get an array with all my clientes from the database.
Then i need to filter this array by the person `id` and show only it's data in a single page.

I have a working code already, but it's only inside a `controller` and I want to use it with a `factory` and a `directive` since i'm no longer using `ng-controller` and this `factory` already make a call to other pages where I need to show client data.

This is what i tried to do with my `factory`:

***app.js***

```
app.factory('mainFactory', function($http){

    var getCliente = function($scope) {
        return $http.get("scripts/php/db.php?action=get_cliente")
        .success( function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(data) {
        });
    };

    var getDetCliente = function($scope,$routeParams) {
        getCliente();
        var mycli = data;
        var myid = $routeParams.id;
        for (var d = 0, len = mycli.length; d < len; d += 1) {
            if (mycli[d].id === myid) {
                return mycli[d];
            }
        }
        return mycli;
    };

    return {
        getCliente: getCliente,
        getDetCliente: getDetCliente
    }
});

app.directive('detClienteTable', function (mainFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: "content/view/det_cliente_table.html",
        link: function($scope) {
            mainFactory.getDetCliente().then(function(mycli) {
                $scope.pagedCliente = mycli;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

***detClient.html***

```
<p>{{pagedCliente.name}}</p>
<p>{{pagedCliente.tel}}</p>
<p>{{pagedCliente.email}}</p>
[...more code...]
```

The problem is, I'm not able to get any data to show in the page, and also, i have no errors in my console.

What may be wrong? 
Keep in mind I'm learning AngularJS.

Comment: One thing I do is return the _promise_ itself, and then the consumers of the factory define their own `.success` behavior.  Not sure if that's "best practice," but it works for me.

Comment: Note that "data" in var mycli = data; is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to implement a promise chain as look into your code looks like you are carrying `getCliente()` promise to  `getDetCliente` method. In that case you need to use `.then` function instead of using `.success` & `.error` which doesn't allow you to continue promise chain. There after from `getDetCliente` function you again need to use `.then` function that gets call when `getCliente` function gets resolved his promise. Your code will reformat it using form it and return `mycli` result.

**Code**

```
var getCliente = function() {
    return $http.get("scripts/php/db.php?action=get_cliente")
    .then( function(res) { //success callback
        return res.data;
    },function(err){ //error callback
       console.log(err)
    })
};

var getDetCliente = function(id) {
    return getCliente().then(function(data){
        var mycli = data;
        var myid = id;
        for (var d = 0, len = mycli.length; d < len; d += 1) {
           if (mycli[d].id === myid) {
              return mycli[d];
           }
        }
        return mycli;
    })
};
```

**Edit**

You shouldn't pass controller `$scope` to the service that will make tight coupling with you directive and controller, Also you want to pass `id` parameter of your route then you need to pass it from directive service call

```
link: function($scope) {
    mainFactory.getDetCliente($routeParams.id).then(function(mycli) {
        $scope.pagedCliente = mycli;
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried but i get an error like this: `TypeError: $http.get(...).then(...).error is not a function` But if i change `.then` to `.success` after the `return $http.get()` in the `getCliente` function, i only have this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: @CelsomTrindade that was my bad..take a look at updated code..I forget to remove `.error` function

Comment: Thanks! It solved, but I still can't get the id from the router param. I'm passing the id vie the $routerParam like this: `/detcliente/:id` Also, i'm using the getClient function to show the full table in a main Client page, but now i can't access the data anymore.

Comment: You should pass that id from you directive call `mainFactory.getDetCliente($routeParams.id).then(function(mycli)` take a look at my edit and updated codwe

Comment: It's kind of working... It's getting the id, but not running properly. If i fill it manually like this "32" then it works, but if i write like 32 (whitout the quotes), it doesn't work. Sorry for these questions, but i'm learning.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade then do strict comapre here `if (mycli[d].id === myid) {` using `===` just use `==`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82337/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-pankajparkar).

Answer (score 1):

You are treating `getCliente` as a synchronous call in `getDetCliente`. Interestingly in your directive you understand that the `getDetCliente` is asynchronous. Change `getCliente` to this and treat it as an asynchronous call when you call it in `getDetCliente`:

```
var getCliente = function($scope) {
    return $http.get("scripts/php/db.php?action=get_cliente");
};
```

Comment: Withyour tip and the other answer i understood what i had to do. Thank you!