# Get an element by id with Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `service` to get (with array) all post from a server. I need to filter this array by id and show only this post in a single page.

In the service I have this code.

```
.service('PostAPI', function($http) {
        this.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get("ajax/getAllPosts.php");
        }
        this.getOne = function(data) {
            return $http.get("ajax/searchPost.php?postID=" + data);
        }
        this.delete = function(data) {
            if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this line?")) {
                return $http.delete("ajax/deletePost.php?postID=" + data);
            }
        }
        this.update = function(data) {
            return $http.put("ajax/updatePost.php?postID" + data);
        }
        this.create = function() {
            return $http.post("ajax/addPost.php");
        }
    })
```

In the controller

```
.controller("PostControlador", function($scope, $routeParams, PostAPI) {
        GetPost();
        $scope.title = "Editar post";

        function GetPost() {
            PostAPI.getOne($routeParams.id).success(function(data) {
                $scope.post = data;
                console.log($scope.post);

            });
        };
```

In post HTML I have this.

```
<div>
  <div>{{post.TASK}}</div>
  <div>{{post.STATUS}}</div>
  <a href="#/posts/"><b>Back</b></a>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get any data to show in the page, and also, i have no errors in my console. ¿Any idea?

Comment: call your getPost(), method after the function definition and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `ajax/searchPost.php?postID=` api that is this api returning single object or array, If this api returning object than it should work but If you getting array of single element in response of api then in your api success code  use first element of array by `data[0]`.

#### Controller code

```
.controller("PostControlador", function($scope, $routeParams, PostAPI) {
    GetPost();
    $scope.title = "Editar post";

    function GetPost() {
        PostAPI.getOne($routeParams.id).success(function(data) {
            $scope.post = data[0];
            console.log($scope.post);

        });
    };
```

Comment: The element return array with object this ID, like this '[Object] 0:
ObjectID:"1" STATUS:"1" TASK: "asas"' I think that i need a asynchronous call to GetPost()

Answer (score 0):

use `then` instaed of `success`. `.then` returns a promise so that you can handle the `asynchrounous` calls.

Also you are calling the `getPost()` method before function definition. So it may not get the promise.

call your `getPost()`, method after the function definition and check, so that it can receive the promise.

```
.controller("PostControlador", function($scope, $routeParams, PostAPI) {

        $scope.title = "Editar post";

        function GetPost() {
            PostAPI.getOne($routeParams.id).then(function(data) {
                $scope.post = data[0];
                console.log($scope.post);

            });
        };

        GetPost();
```

Comment: Yes, and no work, return null. If I checked with console.log($scope.post), return an array with filter one element.

Comment: so, you are gettting your desired result in `console.log`, but not in view?

Comment: pls paste the result of `console.log`

Comment: [Object]0: ObjectID: "1"STATUS: "1"TASK: "asas"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: what is this giving? `console.log(post.TASK)`

Comment: console.log(post.TASK) return 'undefinied'

Comment: I see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213508/angularjs-get-object-by-id-from-factory add a similar error, but i don´t know exactly how fix it.

Comment: so your post object is an array, you  have to take,`$scope.post = data[0];            console.log($scope.post.TASK);`

Comment: I changed my answer pls try this, use `then` instead of `success`

Comment: With then not work, but  $scope.post = data[0] works ^^

Comment: But don´t know why is necessary data[0] in this case, getAll() method works, return array and can print it in a view.

Comment: The `.then` method invokes the handler function with a result object; not a data object.  `data` is a property of the result object. Use `$scope.post = result.data[0];`.